# PHP replace isn't detecting \n\n

Tags: php, str-replace, explode

Text input from an html textarea input box via the POST method :

```
"Paragraph 1.

Paragraph 2."
```

Output from str_replace("\n","(N)",$str) :

```
"Paragraph 1.
(N)
(N)Paragraph 2."
```

While output from str_replace("\n\n","(N)",$str) will be the input, unchanged :

```
"Paragraph 1.

Paragraph 2."
```

**Seemingly "\n\n" is not detectable because it is broken by a newline... Why would this be?**

*Note : ultimately, I'm trying to explode() a string by "\n\n" and not "\n", but same question above applies.*

Comment: double slash for the escape

Comment: It's because you most likely have `\r\n` in the content, so the two `\n\n` do not appear together and therefore aren't matched.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look deeper into the various items for breaking a line. this also worked : preg_split("#\n\s*\n#Uis", $string);

Comment: There could also be other whitespace on the second line, so it might be `\n<space>\n`

Comment: take a look at `\R` which is any linebreak character. see http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#newlineseq